Capture screenshot of active window with title bar and without drop shadow
I'm trying to capture a screenshot of the current window that has my active cursor. But the result is always missing the title bar if that is an application window:
private void CaptureActiveWindow()
{
    IntPtr activeWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

    // Get the client area of the foreground window
    GetClientRect(activeWindowHandle, out Rectangle rect);
    Point topLeft = new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top);

    // Convert the client area's top-left corner to screen coordinates
    ClientToScreen(activeWindowHandle, out topLeft);

    // Create a rectangle in screen coordinates that corresponds to the window's client area
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);

    // Capture the specified screen area
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(bounds.Location, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        SaveImage(bitmap);
    }
}


Can you try GetWindowRect instead of GetClientRect? The latter excludes the title bar.

By the way, the verb Capture has a special meaning in traditional Windows programming and in Windows Forms. It doesn't match what you are asking about at all https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.capture?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

By definition, a window's client area does not include the title bar.

I just want to create an WinForm C# application can capture current active window on monitor like we press both Alt + PrintScreen in default Windows environment, but this application will autosave it into Pictures\Screenshots for me.

@MichaelLiu it does not work at all

so, how can I figure out for this problem @emoacht

See New Ways to do Screen Capture. This allows you to capture window content that's not backed by a GDI redirection surface (such as DirectX content) and comes with a picker selection interface you don't have to implement.

The GetClientRect function returns the client coordinates of the specified window's client area, which by definition excludes the title bar (as well as the border and any menu). To include the title bar, call the DwmGetWindowAttribute (Windows Vista and later) or GetWindowRect function instead. This requires several adjustments to your code:

Declare a RECT type and use it instead of Rectangle in the declarations of DwmGetWindowAttribute and GetWindowRect. (RECT has Right and Bottom fields, whereas Rectangle has Width and Height fields.)
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;

    public Point Location => new Point(Left, Top);
    public int Width => Right - Left;
    public int Height => Bottom - Top;
    public Size Size => new Size(Width, Height);
}

public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
{
    DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 9,
}

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
public static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE dwAttribute, out RECT rect, int cbRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rect);


Both DwmGetWindowAttribute and GetWindowRect return screen coordinates, so delete the ClientToScreen call, and just pass the various RECT values directly to CopyFromScreen:
IntPtr activeWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
RECT rect;

try
{
    // Get the window bounds excluding any drop shadow
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(
        activeWindowHandle, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
        out rect, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RECT)));
}
catch (EntryPointNotFoundException) // Windows XP and earlier
{
    GetWindowRect(activeWindowHandle, out rect);
}

// Capture the specified screen area
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, rect.Size);
    }

    SaveImage(bitmap);
}


The GetWindowRect function is virtualized for DPI. To ensure that this doesn't cause any problems, add an application manifest file (App.manifest) to your project, and opt into the dpiAware setting:
<dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>




Even it not solution for my problem but still vote it. thanks

@ThuongVoTinh: This code worked for me on Windows 10; I was able to capture Calculator and Notepad. If it doesn't work for you, please provide additional details. For example, step through the code with a debugger and provide the result of GetWindowRect.

Yes, my full source code is here, as edited with your solution: link

Using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, I created a project using the "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" project template, pasted your code, added App.manifest using the "Application Manifest File" file template, uncommented the <dpiAware> section, and ran the application. I then started Notepad and pressed F9. A screenshot of Notepad was successfully placed into my Pictures\Screenshots folder.

I'll try again and response.

Hi @Michael Liu, hope you still interested in this topic. I created new project same as you mentioned. And the result for window capture always not fix border as window does. You can see here link. And dpiAware as you mentioned: link.

Strongly confirmed that your answer is saved my issue! Thank you so much. Some of your update code is not familiar with me. Will read it to learn.
